# SVG with Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to do a SVG graph with D3 (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js) where the bar width is defined manually and the thing has a horizontal scroll..

I have a working fiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/bikrantsharma/zw264tfc/12/

This is how my scales are defined

```
var barWidth = 30,
  paddingFactor = 2.2,
  responsiveDIVHeight = 300,
  responsiveDIVWidth = tempData.length * barWidth * paddingFactor;



var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, responsiveDIVWidth], 0.5)
  .domain(tempData.map(function(d) {
    return d.Type
  })),
  y = d3.scale.linear().rangeRound([responsiveDIVHeight, 0])
  .domain([0, d3.max(tempData, function(d) {
    return (d.Count + 10);
  })]),
```

There are two problems which i need help with:

1. The Bars are flipped in opposite direction. How to get the div flipped or the bars transformed?
2. The height of the bar comes a slightly less than the actual value. So for e.g if the Count is '5' bar height comes back as 4.8 or something. What is the issue there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your bars are **not** flipped. What's happening here is very simple: You have two SVGs, one at the top and one at the bottom, and you're drawing the rectangles in the bottom SVG. How can the rectangles magically appear in the *top* SVG? It's not possible.

Instead of that, draw the SVGs **side by side**. The left one, with the vertical axis, has `float: left` in the style of the `<div>` it is in, and the right one, scrollable, has `overflow-x: scroll` in the style of the `<div>` it is in.

Here is a demo making the minimal possible changes in your code:

```js
var tempData = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
  var obj = {

    "Id": 1,
    "Type": 'A' + i,
    "Count": 5
  };
  tempData.push(obj);
}


var barWidth = 30,
  paddingFactor = 2.2,
  padding = 20,
  responsiveDIVHeight = 300,
  responsiveDIVWidth = tempData.length * barWidth * paddingFactor;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, responsiveDIVWidth], 0.5)
  .domain(tempData.map(function(d) {
    return d.Type
  })),
  y = d3.scale.linear().rangeRound([responsiveDIVHeight - padding, padding])
  .domain([0, d3.max(tempData, function(d) {
    return (d.Count + 10);
  })]),
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom'),
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient('left');


var svgY = d3.select('#verticalSVG')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('height', responsiveDIVHeight)
  .attr("width", 50);

svgY.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .call(yAxis)
  .attr('dx', '-0.3em')
  .attr('transform', "translate(50, 0)");;

var svgX = d3.select('#horizontalSVG')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', responsiveDIVWidth)
  .attr('height', responsiveDIVHeight);

svgX.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x axis')
  .attr('transform', "translate(0," + (responsiveDIVHeight - padding) + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll('text')
  .attr('dx', '-0.8em')
  .attr('dy', '-.15em')
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return "rotate(-60)"
  });


var startPoint = 0;

var bar = svgX.selectAll('.bar')
  .data(tempData)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('y', function(d) {
    return y(d.Count)
  })
  .attr('x', function(d) {
    return x(d.Type)
  })
  .attr('width', barWidth)
  .attr('height', function(d) {
    return responsiveDIVHeight - y(d.Count) - padding
  })
```

```css
.legend-main-div {
  padding: 2%;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">

    <div id="verticalSVG" style="float:left">

    </div>
    <div id="horizontalSVG" style="overflow-x:scroll">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Gerardo.. you saved me again..i am all new to this..and trying out few things before using it in our application..Thanks again for the help.I am going to have a question on wrapping too and was wondering if you can chime in on that too..